# Making the attributes of the first cell of tableviewcell change position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom header in the table view cell and when i initialise it it overlaps the first cell of the tableview cell and if i increase the size of the first cell of the tableviewcell the buttons and label all go out of their positions .This is the code.

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
    return 100;
}
else{
    return 75;
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to increase the height of the first cell without messing up the postion of button and labels?

Comment: I guess you need to create your button and labels relative to the cell height instead of hard coding y and height values.

Comment: Basically what @JasperPol said. Maybe try taking a look at Auto Layout?

Comment: Also try setting `cell.clipsToBounds = YES;`

Comment: Thanks it seems i have to use the autolayout..